# The computer doesn't start after hibernation on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, hibernate

I've recently updated my Dell Precision M3800 from Ubuntu 14.10 to Ubuntu 15.04. Hibernation doesn't work properly: the computer hibernates but doesn't wake up. This only happens after I run Ubuntu 15.04 for some time, i.e. if I start Ubuntu and hibernate immediately or after just launching one or two applications, hibernation works just fine. But if I run Ubuntu for a little longer and launch few application, allocating almost all memory (but not all completely), the computer doesn't wake up after hibernation. It looks like it's going to but it hangs up after screen with a cursor on it. I also noticed some strange swapoff -a behavior, it cleans swap but not disabling it.

Comment: I experience same  problem.  I updated to 15.04 from 14.04 just because hibernation not working on my new laptop (Lenovo E550) at all. It's crucial function for me.